# gcc compiler flag to suppress template expansion for template errors during compilation?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc, compiler-construction

I'm wondering if there is a flag or modification for the gcc compiler that will return a line number and sentence explaining the type of error when it encounters an error involving templates, but will **not** print the page of template expansion code spaghetti that invariably follow such errors.

For example, instead of an error like this:

```
temp.cc:9: error: ‘class std::map<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::less<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > >, std::allocator<std::pair<const std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> >, std::basic_string<char,     std::char_traits<char>, std::allocator<char> > > > >’ has no member named ‘hat’
```

I would like something like this:

```
temp.cc:9: error: class has no member named hat.
```

Comment: Pipe output through sed or perl script?

Comment: Try Clang - this is one of the design feature of clang frontend.

Answer (score 1):

There isnt one. The compiler is trying to help you identify the class that is causing the problem. It only knows of that class as the expansion of its template types.

Comment: It trys to help, but STL user has no need to see all bunch of char_traits.... which are needed by STL developer.

Answer (score 0):

The gcc has no flag for this, but `sed` could easily solve the job.