# How to hide defaulted template parameters in gcc error messages?

Tags: c++, templates, gcc

Reading through error messages generated by g++ is often a pain because gcc expand names like

```
std::ostream
```

in my code into a much longer form like

```
std::basic_ostream<char, std::char_traits<char> >
```

in the error messages. Similarly, gcc expands `std::string` into `std::basic_string<char>`. I don't see any benefit for such expansions, and it only makes it difficult for me to relate the error messages and the error site.

I was wondering if it is possible tell gcc to disable this expansion behavior and use the shorter names with defaulted template parameters as-is?

There is a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6963892/) which seems to be about not showing the long expanded name at all. I am asking here if it is possible to just show the short name as I used in the code. The answer there also didn't solve the problem.

Comment: clang is pretty good at this

Comment: Whether gcc will print the typedef or not depends on the context, template errors for instance will always spit out the complete type as IIRC making template error vomit even slightly more readable is no trivial matter. Non-template errors, for instance calling a non existent method of `ofstream` use the typedef (in GCC 4.9 at least).

Answer (score 2):

There is no compiler flag to reduce or change the error messages and the related types/templates.

- gcc suppports coloring since gcc 4.9 with `-fdiagnostics-color={auto, always, never}`. See the documentation [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc-4.9.0/gcc/Language-Independent-Options.html#index-fdiagnostics-color-252).

---

A number of third party tools exist to help you decrypt error messages:

- [GCCFilter](http://www.mixtion.org/gccfilter/) for coloring and simplification of error messages (Perl script)
- [ColorGCC](http://schlueters.de/colorgcc.html) in the same vein (Perl script), git is [here](https://github.com/johannes/colorgcc).
- [STLFilt](http://www.bdsoft.com/tools/stlfilt.html) : A message filter designed for STL-related diagnostics. Note that it is not supported/developed anymore.

Also as a (very good) alternative, [the **clang** compiler is very, very good at diagnosis and error messages](http://clang.llvm.org/diagnostics.html).

Comment: Coloring is useless since GCC 4.9, which includes `-fdiagnostics-color={auto, always, never}`.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt you can right now. A kind of close option is `fno-pretty-templates` which acts as follows:

> -fno-pretty-templates
>   When an error message refers to a specialization of a function template, the compiler normally prints the signature of
>   the template followed by the template arguments and any typedefs or
>   typenames in the signature (e.g. void f(T) [with T = int] rather than
>   void f(int)) so that it's clear which template is involved. When an
>   error message refers to a specialization of a class template, the
>   compiler omits any template arguments that match the default template
>   arguments for that template. If either of these behaviors make it
>   harder to understand the error message rather than easier, you can use
>   -fno-pretty-templates to disable them.